# subset a data frame by group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
dput(test)
test <- structure(list(Blocking = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L,     
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
ID69 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ID70 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), ID71 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), ID72 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), ID73 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
ID74 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ID75 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), ID77 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("Blocking", 
"Treatment", "ID69", "ID70", "ID71", "ID72", "ID73", "ID74", 
"ID75", "ID77"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L
))
```

I would like to split it based on `treatment` into four data frames. I tried the following code:

```
 treatments <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
 subset_list <- lapply(treatments, function(x, input_df = test){
 subset(input_dt, treatment=treatments)
 })

 names(subset_list) <- treatments
```

I get a list but individual data frames are the full test df's and do not contain rows only corresponding to the treatment. This seems like a really easy question, but I am missing a crucial detail here and I am new to the apply family. Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: `split(test, treatments)` ?

Comment: Yup, tried your solution. It works! Had not used `split` before and was trying to get habituated to `apply`

Comment: `lapply(treatments, function(x) subset(input_dt, Treatment == x))` is what you wanted there.

Comment: Thank you!! if you write that as an answer I will accept it. I find the usage of x in functions a little hard to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()`:

```
split(test, treatments)
```

`res <- split(x, f)` divides the data into the groups defined by `f` into a list.

`unsplit(res, f)` does the opposite.

Comment: Thanks, I have upvoted your answer. I spent so long figuring out an `lapply` solution, I wanted to understand its correct form here as the accepted solution. Your code does the job in 1 line instead of 2 though, I will remember to use `split` in the future